# Rails 5 active admin installation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am new to rails and trying to add active admin on latest version of ruby 2.3.0 and rails5 . i have added below line in gem file :

```
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
```

did bundle install and then i run the server and i am getting the below error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/inherited_resources-6fa6e5b9d29c/lib/inherited_resources.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>': break from proc-closure (LocalJumpError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_controller/api.rb:145:in `<class:API>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_controller/api.rb:88:in `<module:ActionController>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_controller/api.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jbuilder-2.6.1/lib/jbuilder/railtie.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:33:in `block in on_load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:32:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:32:in `on_load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jbuilder-2.6.1/lib/jbuilder/railtie.rb:19:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Sites/second_project/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Sites/second_project/config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
        from C:/Sites/second_project/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from C:/Sites/second_project/config.ru:in `new'
        from C:/Sites/second_project/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:318:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:218:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:124:in `log_to_stdout'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:77:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I google these error but it seems code error however i have not written any code in newly created project just trying to install active admin for practise.
Please help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a [recent bug](https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources/issues/428).  Just use the latest version from RubyGems, not GitHub.  If you omit inherited_resources from your Gemfile this should be done for you by default.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would use in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'inherited_resources'
```

Looking at 'inherited_resources' github repository, it looks likes the current version in the repo is broken. As a best practice try to use versions of gem that you can control (the call above is not even really clean for a production app)

You may also fall on some SSL error after so to fix this, just add the following to your Gemfile

```
gem 'openssl', '>=2.0.3'
```

Comment: getting error on openssl ,*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.